# Not able to update state using localStorage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, local-storage, use-effect

I am trying log back in using the stored credentials but it doesn't work and I have tried everything . The dispatch function works fine with the form but it doesn't works with the localStorage .

**App.tsx :**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const userDetails=localStorage.getItem('user')
    if (userDetails) { 
      const user= JSON.parse(userDetails);
      login(user); // dispatch function
    }
  });
```

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue is. What's the expected result and what is happening instead?

Comment: Are you setting the storage? Is useEffect execution delayed (async)? And also... Just don't use localStorage for store a password/sensible content, it is a HUGE security risk! Prefer tokens or any other oauth method but not plain text password/details!

Comment: I have tried everything , even consoled the value and it shows the actual object ,have also used async await but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure, value in the localStorage and useEffect should be called just once — on the component mount stage; I recommend sending the value through the props. With this approach, it will be much easier to guess what is going on.

```js
const ParentComponent = () => (
    <Component
        user={
            JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        }
    />
)

const Component = ({
    user
}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        login(user); // dispatch function
    }, [user]);

    return <></>
};
```